# ng-repeat not working properly when using key and value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my program iam trying to display the resultant array using ng-repeat with key      and    value but is not working properly.But the output is displayed correctly in console. 
I think its a simple mistake but iam not able to figure it out. Here is the code.

```
   app.controller("taglistcontroller",function($scope,MyService1)
  {   
    var photodetails=MyService1.getProperty1();
var array=[];

angular.forEach(photodetails, function(value1) 

    { 
        var sample=value1.tag;
        angular.forEach(sample, function(value,key) 
        {
           var tagvalue=value;
            var temp=array[tagvalue];
            if(temp === undefined)
            {
              array[tagvalue]=1;  
            }
            else
            {
                temp++;
                array[tagvalue]=temp;
            }


        });

    });     
          $scope.outputtaglist= array;
                            console.log(array);
});
```

html code

```
<H2>Tag list </H2>
             <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in outputtaglist">
           {{key}} {{value}}
           </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `(key, value)` only works if the object to loop over is a key/value object. In this case you are using an array so it only has value's and an index which you can find in `$index`

```
<div ng-repeat="value in outputtaglist">
  {{$index}} {{value}}
</div>
```

Furthermore, it looks like your creating your array as if it's an object(technically it is, but thats not the problem right now..), you might just want to instance it with

```
var array={};
```

Comment: yes now it worked, I changed the array declaration to var array={};